# How to use CollectionViewSource with design time data in Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

I wonder how I can show design time data in Expression Blend that is located inside a SampleData.xaml using a CollectionViewSource? Before changing my code to use the CVS, I used an ObservableCollection. I was in the need to filter and sort the items inside there, thus I changed the code to use the CVS. Now my designer complains about not being able to fill the SampleData's NextItems with a proper structure to show up in Expression Blend. Here is some code I use inside the app:

MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        NextItems = new CollectionViewSource();
        NextItems.Source = AllItems;
    }

    public CollectionViewSource NextItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> AllItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    some functions to fill, filter, sort etc...
}
```

MainView.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ... some other stuff ...
    d:DesignWidth="480"
    d:DesignHeight="728"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleData.xaml}">

    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="Transparent">
        <controls:Panorama>
            <controls:PanoramaItem>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NextItems.View}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

SampleData.xaml

```
<local:MainViewModel
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppNamespace"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:swd="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=System.Windows" >
    <local:MainViewModel.AllItems>
        <local:ItemModel
            FullName="Dummy"
            Image="/Images/dummy.png" />
    </local:MainViewModel.AllItems>

    <local:MainViewModel.NextItems>

        How to fill the CollectionViewSource's Source?

    </local:MainViewModel.NextItems>
</local:MainViewModel>
```

So the question I can't find an answer to is how to  fill the Source for NextItems in SampleDate.xaml? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show sample data in the designer I would recommend you to do it from code. There are two ways of generating sample data for the Blend Designer or the VStudio designer:

1. From an XML file as you do.
2. From a **c# class** -> Best option

best option.

In WPF, in windows 8 and in WP7.5 and highger, you can access a propertie called:`Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled` making use of it you can seed your ObservableCollection from your view model:

```
    public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            AllItems = FakeDataProvider.FakeDataItems;
        }
        NextItems.Source = AllItems;
    }

    public CollectionViewSource NextItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> AllItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

In this way, if you change the model, you dont' have to regenerate an XML file, it's a little bit cleaner from a C# file. The FakeDataProvider is an static class where all design-time fake data are stored. So in you XAML the only thing you have to do is to bind your **Listbox** to the collection of your ViewModel.