# XAML: Nested properties error in preview data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML file that includes sample data to preview XAML designs:

```
<data:MyClass 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:com.meta.Data;assembly=com.meta.framework"
    xmlns:data1="clr-namespace:com.alle.Data;assembly=com.meta.framework">

    <data:MyClass.RandomItems>
        <data1:Parent.Child Title="Hede0" Description="Hodo0" />
        <data1:Parent.Child Title="Hede1" Description="Hodo1" />
        <data1:Parent.Child Title="Hede2" Description="Hodo2" />
        <data1:Parent.Child Title="Hede3" Description="Hodo3" />
    </data:MyClass.RandomItems>

</data:MyClass>
```

I get the error Error:

```
Nested properties are not supported: Parent.Child
```

I also have `ObservableCollection<Parent.Child> RandomItems` in `MyClass` and everything works fine at runtime.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please don't use java naming convention in C#. "com.meta.framework"? what the hell is that.

Comment: Ahahaha, i just wrote an example, this is not an actual code. But you are right, i am more familiar with java ;)

Comment: I have answered a very similar question here, hope to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072157/how-to-use-collectionviewsource-with-design-time-data-in-expression-blend/18726607#18726607